# SVN Merge branch to trunk with ignored versioned files

Tags: svn, merge, branch

So I have a project with the folders /trunk /branches and /tags in SVN
When a developer creates a branch to code, there are some files that he needs to change for the test ambient, so these files needed to be ignored but they are versioned (templates are out of question here).
What we are planning to do is commit those files to the branch and when we merge the branch to the trunk we don't include the revision of this change. Example:

r10 - create trunk 1.0.1
r11 - developer changes and commits files on branch 1.0.1 that are not supposed to go to trunk
r12 - developer commits new feature on branch 1.0.1
r13 - more features on branch 1.0.1
r14 - merge only r12 and r13 to trunk

Is this OK? Are we going to have any problems?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It's OK. But you have 2 possible additional solutions (random order, without ordering on convenience and efficiency)

- Perform additional merge(s) before (full-range) main code merge: merge **config files only** with  `--accept 'mine-conflict'` (ignore branch-changes in configs)
- Merge (full range again) with `--diff3-cmd SOMETOOL`, where SOMETOOL is specially created tool, which will ignore all changes in config-files only